# Oracle :: Calling Packaged Stored Procedures

Tags: oracle, plsql, messagebroker

In my Project i have stored procedure in package i like to call it directly in my project like `HRPKG.ADD_JOB_HISTORY` it retuen `Stored procedure is not defined` but if i called it like from UserName like `HR.HRPKG.ADD_JOB_HISTORY` it called successfully

**Note : I Connect wit oracle using ODBC In Message Broker !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer your SP directly without any username.You need your username/schema name for reference.If you dont use any User then how will it know where to take the SP from.Its the syntax.

```
HR.HRPKG.ADD_JOB_HISTORY
```

HR-uname
 HRPKG-package
 ADD_JOB_HISTORY-SP

It goes like find the SP ADD_JOB_HISTORY under the package HRPKG in HR schema

Comment: I have three Environments === three Oracle Databases , Tables and procedures are same but users are different ... i need to call the procedures from packages ...

Comment: you need a schema name for sure.What do you mean by users in you context?

Comment: I mean the Schema name .. ie : the First Database Environtment we Call it `HR.HRPKG`, in Second Environment `INFO.HRPKG` and in Third one is `PROD.HRPKG`...

Comment: I hope you understand the use of Schemas.Make the appropriate connections for each and every user that you have to connect.you cannot use the package the way you think.you need a name to tell the compiler where to access the data.when there is more than 1 schema u need to use the schema name.i think you should understand the use of those inorder to understand the whole thing.

Comment: Last Question ... I am accessing the schema in odbc using username and password , so when i am calling the package it supposed to call the package without Schema name! isn't it !!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66642/discussion-between-thedbguy-and-abu-taha).